# Simple Parallel processing chunks of pandas Dataframe with groupby and aggregate operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

Edit: I found the mistake, i forgot to actually return the data in my aggregation function... whoops.
Anyway, there's a couple of methods listed below, i'll leave them here for reference.

Original:
I need to apply a rather computationally expensive groupby and aggregate on a pandas dataframe.

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'],as_index=False).aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

I cannot use Map for this (or maybe i do, i have no idea anymore), since i need access to multiple lines of the data in order for the two column groupby to work.
Using Pool.map just returns the same df, as is expected, because it passes the data row by row instead of group-by-group or at least as a whole chunk.

What i want is simple:

- split the Dataframe in n Slices/Chunks (np.array_split works well for this i think),
- apply the groupby and aggregate on each slice (just a normal operation on each slice)
- then merge the slices together (pd.concat)

this really shouldn't be very hard should it? But every example and tutorial is fixated on row-by-row operations which make the groupby/aggregate do nothing.

Thanks for you help :)

EDIT:

I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
num_partitions = 10 #number of partitions to split dataframe
num_cores = 4 #number of cores on your machine
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, [group for name,group in df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])]))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
def aggregate_fun(data):
    data = data.groupby(['Col1','Col2'],as_index=False).aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
    return data
```

EDIT2:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
ppe = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)

futures = []
results = []
for group in np.split(df, 4):
    p = ppe.submit(aggregate_fun, group)
    futures.append(p)

for future in as_completed(futures):
    r = future.result()
    results.append(r)

df_output = pd.concat(results)
```

Both methods works, so long as you don't forget to have your function actually return something :P 
It is however not as big a speedup as i would hope, 
note that i forgot to allocate the data variable before returning or just returning the aggregation result... Goes to show that coding should not be done late in the afternoon.

Comment: I don't have time to put an example together but you want to iterate through the `groupby`  `for name, group in df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']):`

Comment: @piRSquared i already tried that, no performance difference. the question then is how to create threads in order to parallellize the loop. Is there a way to map to each group? by telling the Pool.map function to take groups maybe?
i should mention i have no experience in multithreading :P

Comment: @piRSquared well it turns out i'm a doofus, and forgot to have my function return anything :P